# CSS not showing in IE (any version)

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I am doing some final testing of my site before it goes live. I have built it in Chrome and I am finding all the things that done work in IE!

I have a sprite that I built that is not showing in IE...

HTML

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/111035429397283398622/" target="_blank"><img src="http://127.0.0.1:600/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/spacer.gif" class="sprite social plus1" alt="Join our Circles on Google+" /></a>

<a href="http://www.facebook.com/primorisfinancial" target="_blank"><img src="http://127.0.0.1:600/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/spacer.gif" class="sprite social facebook" alt="Like Primoris Financial on Facebook" /></a>

<a href="http://au.linkedin.com/in/benjaminirons" target="_blank"><img src="http://127.0.0.1:600/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/spacer.gif" class="sprite social linkedin" alt="Benjamin Irons on LinkedIn" /></a>

<a href="http://primorisfinancial.blogspot.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://127.0.0.1:600/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/spacer.gif" class="sprite social blogger" alt="Primoris Financial on Blogger" /></a>

<a href="http://twitter.com/PrimorisFinPlan" target="_blank"><img src="http://127.0.0.1:600/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/spacer.gif" class="sprite social twitter" alt="Follow Primoris Financial on Twitter" /></a>

<a href="http://www.youtube.com/PrimorisFinancial" target="_blank"><img src="http://127.0.0.1:600/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/spacer.gif" class="sprite social youtube" alt="Primoris Financial on YouTube" /></a>
```

with the following CSS

```
.sprite {background:url(http://127.0.0.1:600/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Social-CSS-Sprite-Test.png);}
    .social {height:32px;}

/* Social Buttons */

        .plus1 {width:32px; background-position:0px 0px;}
        .facebook {width:32px; background-position:-33px 0px;}
        .linkedin {width:32px; background-position:-66px 0px;}
        .blogger {width:32px; background-position:-99px 0px;}
        .twitter {width:32px; background-position:-132px 0px;}
        .youtube {width:32px; background-position:-165px 0px
```

;}

Comment: You can't go live with URL pointing to localhost.

Comment: He isn't live yet so that's not the problem at hand

Comment: Do you know what version of IE?

Comment: Yep, the URL's will change when the website is uploaded and live, testing to make everything shows up before uploading.. The sprite generates in Chrome, but not in IE

Comment: Put that image in a remote server & use that link on sprite class.

Comment: IE 9, I tried in the developer mode 7 and 8 also, didnt work..

Comment: Don't change the URL when going live, or you won't be able to maintain your site. Just use **relative** URL.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main problems as far as I can see is that you are linking to the image in your CSS without using quotation/speech marks. And as dystroy said, don't hard link to the image, it's best to do it relatively like this:

```
{background:url('../wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Social-CSS-Sprite-Test.png');}
```

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the src from your images (better use span than img).

Fix the URL in your css to be relative and not point to 127.0.0.1 (localhost).

Check that you have the correct HTML headers :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: And don't forget to make all the html valid!